# Is writing quality regulated by the UK Sale of Goods Act

Tags: consumer-protection, england-and-wales, freedom-of-speech

When products are sold in England and Wales there there is an implied contract term that *the goods supplied under the contract are of satisfactory quality*. ([Sale of Goods Act, Section 14](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1979/54#section-14))

Does this mean that consumers are entitled to a refund if a book is badly written?

Of course in many cases it would be hard for a court to judge writing quality objectively, and I suppose the policy aims of allowing free expression and consumer protection would be in conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The Act further clarifies that

> For the purposes of this Act, goods are of satisfactory quality if they meet the standard that a reasonable person would regard as satisfactory, taking account of any description of the goods, the price (if relevant) and all the other relevant circumstances.

When you buy the book, you're doing so because you have an expectation the story will be entertaining, or having it available is somehow useful to you.

Unless you have been lied to, by the bookseller, the fact that your expectation does not match what happened is not the problem of the seller of the book. Moreover, especially when you physically purchase the book from a brick-and-mortar shop yourself, unless the book has never been opened or read by anybody, you have had ample opportunity to check whether the book is of suitable quality for your purpose, as a reasonable person would do.

As a consumer you are protected from books being printed on tissue and bound with spider webs (durable), with invisible ink (fit for purpose), covered with razor blades (safe), and generally not tatty (suitable appearance and finish; freedom from minor defect).

As such, there is no conflict between consumer protection and free expression. You are assured a book you can read for a long time, and should you dislike the story, you're also free to burn it (subject to pollution and hazard laws).

Comment: This seems like you are giving your own opinion. Has any of this been stated by the courts?

Comment: Buyers typically read only a tiny fraction of a book before buying it — not enough to know if they will enjoy the work as a whole. And for a non-fiction book readers who are not experts on the subject are unlikely to be competent to judge the quality in advance.

Comment: But that is not the bookseller's problem. A reasonable person attempts to decide a likelihood that they will enjoy the book or find it worthwhile to possess, and makes their decision based on that likelihood; it may come from reviews, from familiarity with the author, from recommendations by acquaintances, or a requirements from some educational or professional body. Finding it's terrible after my friend said it was great is our problem; finding it's terrible after I bought it for the red cover is just simple unreasonability and therefore irrelevant.

Comment: If I buy a hammer, without reading reviews, because I like the red paint on it and it breaks the first time I try to use it to drive a nail I would presumably be entitled to a refund. Where are you seeing the difference with a book?

Comment: A hammer that breaks on first use is clearly neither durable nor fit for purpose, it's not a relevant comparison here. If you bought a red object because it was red and it happened to be a hammer, then you have no real complaint either, since you weren't expecting it to do anything except be red, which it was.

Comment: If a book is badly written, it is arguably not fit for purpose.

Comment: "Badly written" to one person is an artistic challenging of linguistic norms to another. Disliking *Twilight* because of its shallow plot and implicit promotion of relationship abuse in young adults, does not prevent it being a story written for entertainment purposes, and someone that buys it only to complain about said features as bad writing, for example, cannot say the book is illegible or unreadable or that it was not intended to entertain, only that it ended up not doing so for that individual.

Comment: You arent buying a story, you are buying the book. The quality of the good refers to the physical quality of the book (e.g. howbwell bound it was, missing pages, badly typeset/inked etc.) and NOT the quality of the story written in it. You go to a bookstore to buy a book, not a story.

Comment: @Nij I'm not talking about shallow plots or distasteful themes.  I'm talking about writing that is so bad I can't decipher what the author means to say.  Suppose, for example, that you bought a book describing how to grow vegetables, but on taking it home you found that only 10% of the sentences even contain a verb, so you can't follow the instructions.

Comment: That's your problem for having an unreasonable expectation. A court would ask you whether you bothered to open the thin at all before buying it; no? Basic background not even attempted, dismissed.

Comment: We could extend @phoog's scenario slightly and say that the book was shrinkwrapped, and the buyer wasn't permitted to look inside it before buying it.

Comment: @bdsl indeed, your timing is excellent: just a couple of days ago, I bought a shrink-wrapped tourist guidebook full of nearly incomprehensible English that appeared to have been very poorly translated from Italian.

Comment: @phoog haha, I promise I wasn't stalking you. I was reminded of this question by a twitter about an old book of advice on how to cycle on the roads.

Comment: @phoog did you get a refund for the guidebook?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that consumers are entitled to a refund if a book is badly written?

The questioner refers to "consumers". Therefore [user4657's answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/18464/45080), and [Teresa Pelka](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/5669/teresa-pelka)'s [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/18584/45080), are both wrong for failing to cite and apply the [Consumer Rights Act 2015](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/80427/45080).

I quote from Janet O'Sullivan, [*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's Law of Contract*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/osullivan-and-hilliards-the-law-of-contract-9780198853176?) (2020 9 ed), p 207. The [2022 10 ed](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/osullivan-and-hilliards-the-law-of-contract-9780192856555?) shall be published in July 2022.

> 8.27 According to s 61 of the CRA, a ‘consumer contract’ is defined in s 61(1) as a ‘contract between a trader and a consumer’. In turn, ‘trader’ and ‘consumer’ are defined in s 2 of the CRA as follows:
>
> (2) ‘Trader’ means a person acting for purposes relating to that person’s trade, business, craft or profession, whether acting personally or through another person acting in the trader’s name or on the trader’s behalf.
>
> (3) ‘Consumer’ means an individual acting for purposes that are wholly or mainly outside that individual’s trade, business, craft or profession.
>
> (4) A trader claiming that an individual was not acting for purposes wholly or mainly outside the individual’s trade, business, craft or profession must prove it.

Consumers ought to start with the CRA 2015, which protects Consumers way more than the Sale of Goods Act 1979.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question - can you add a conclusion, perhaps based on your reading of the CRA 2015, or ideally any readings of it from the courts?

I suppose there are three possible answers: (1) yes it is regulated, courts have awarded compensation to buyers of bad books, (2) no it is not regulated, courts have consistently refused to do that, or (3) it is legally uncertain, few or no disputes of this kind have appeared before the courts, courts have made a strongly binding rule.

Comment: @bdsl You are correct that this does not DEFINITIVELY answer the question. I didn't have time to write a conclusion, because I shall need days to research the most recent case law on the CRA 2015. I shall try to do this. Remind me if I forget.

Comment: @user43343 this is your reminder.